# JPA AttributeConverter is being ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-8

I am trying to use an AttributeConverter to store the new Java 8 ZonedDateTime values in a MySQL database (DATETIME field) using Hibernate 4.3.0.

When I try to execute an update I get this error:

```
...Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '\xAC\xED\x00\x05sr\x00\x0Djava.time.Ser\x95]\x84\xBA\x1B"H\xB2\x0C\x00\x00xpw\x0D\x06\x00\x00\x07\xE0\x02\x11\x0B&\xEE\xE0\x08\x' for column...
```

I have read many SO answers saying to use the converter approach, so I wrote one:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ZonedDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {
    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime) {
        if (zonedDateTime == null) return null;

        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(zonedDateTime.toLocalDate());
    }

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        if (date == null) return null;

        LocalDate localDate = date.toLocalDate();
        return ZonedDateTime.from(localDate);
    }
}
```

... but it never gets called.

I have even added `jpaProperties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class, hbm");` to my jpaProperties, but no luck. The ZonedDateTimeConverter class is in the same package as my Entities, so it should get scanned.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you also try annotating the attribute(s) to be converted with the annotation `@Convert(converter = ZonedDateTimeConverter.class)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it with/without those annotations and the "autoApply" set to true/false; all combinations give the same result.

Comment: Just a general comment on your converter ... you say you want to persist in a DATETIME field, yet you are only storing the DATE by using a java.sql.Date. You could have converted to java.util.Date and that has the time also

Answer (score 12):

Reading JPA 2.1 spec :

"The conversion of all basic types is supported except for the following: Id attributes (including the
attributes of embedded ids and derived identities), version attributes, relationship attributes, and
attributes explicitly annotated as Enumerated or Temporal or designated as such in the XML descriptor."

any chance your ZonedDateTime field is annotated with @Id or @Temporal  in your entity ?

Comment: I had replaced the `@Temporal` with the `@Convert`, but as I just posted in my own answer, this was my own fault.  The entity in question is not being managed by Hibernate (nor any other JPA provider).

Comment: Thanks, fixed my issue! I had both an `@Convert` and `@Temporal` on one of my fields fields, where the Converter was being ignored and giving an error at the retrieval of the value. After removing `@Temporal` it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this was my mistake.  Part of my application is managed by Hibernate, but part of it is NOT.  The object I'm having problems with is NOT managed by Hibernate, so it makes sense that the JPA stuff isn't getting called.